# Apply Js to show or hide elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to show a select option and then show a input to filter

here's my js code

```js
function showSearch(id) {
    if (id == "statusSearch") {
          $("#statusSearch").show();
          $("#monthSearch").hide();
          $("#employeeSearch").hide();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, it doesn't show anything. Only my first select option

```html
       <select id="status" name="status" onChange="showSearch(this.value);">
            <option selected disabled>Select</option>
            <option name="statusSearch">Estado de OT</option>
            <option name="monthSearch">Mes</option>
            <option name="employeeSearch">Empleado</option>
        </select> 
        <button type="submit">Ver todo</button>
```

Example, if I choose "statusSearch"

```html
<div id="statusSearch" style="display: none;">
        <h2>Estado de OT</h2>
        <select type="text" name="searchByStatus">
                <option selected disabled>Elegir</option>
                <option name="open">Abierta</option>
                <option name="closed">Cerrada</option>           
        </select>
</div>
```

And it's my view

```php
$req3=$request;

if($req3) {
            $query = trim($req3->get('statusSearch')); 
            $search = MaintenanceTasks::select('Employee_Id_created','Task_Id','Machine_Id',
            'Request_date')//etc      
            ->get();        
        }
```

Well, I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use value="statusSearch" than name="statusSearch" on your options

example :

```
<option selected disabled>Select</option>
<option value="statusSearch">Estado de OT</option>
<option value="monthSearch">Mes</option>
<option value="employeeSearch">Empleado</option>
```

like here https://codepen.io/JUSEN/pen/dyOperB?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not correct:

```
function showSearch(id) {
   $( "#statusSearch option" ).each(function( index ) {


    if (id == "statusSearch") {
          $("#statusSearch option).each(function(  ) {
            if($this).attr('name') == "statusSearch"){
               $(this).show();
              
            }else if($this).attr('name') == "monthSearch"){
               $(this).hide();
              
            }else if {
              //and so on
             :
         });//end each
```